# How to add hash after domain in every url in react js

Tags: reactjs

I have one application in react which are working on fine and I am developing  new app in react and its working in local machine when I uploaded on server it not worked when I added hash after domain it working, the old app also having hash in url. I did not get how to add the hash in url for every page. If I open url it will automatically add hash like this

> [www.example.com/#/signin](http://www.example.com/#/signin)
> [www.example.com/#/about](http://www.example.com/#/about)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `<BrowserRouter>` to `<HashRouter>`